# Revive Adserver Vast videoClickThroughURL redirect not redirecting

Tags: vast, advertisement-server

I've just upgraded to v5.3.1 (not sure previous version) and my videoClickThroughURL goes to a blank white page and never redirects. I'm using Vast and everything worked perfect before the upgrade, so I'm a little perplexed. My Revive Adserver uses `http:`: and my redirect is `http:` so there's no mixed ssl. Is there something new I need to do with this latest version?

`[http://fakeadserverserver.com]/adserver/www/delivery/cl.php?bannerid=5&zoneid=5&sig=8ddfd06f8ab42ed0d44e0737ab7253b77dbe38ce493cd18da3b52caf62607091&dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com`

I'm doing this from a mobile app, but I don't think that matters. The page above does load, but it's a blank white page and never redirects. I can see the click registers in Revive, so it appears to be an issue with redirecting.